# How can I compile list of hashes from dictionary

Tags: python

I am working on this code that is supposed to be compiling a list of all of the MD5 hashes in the **example** dictionary, but I am sure this is not right. How can I fix it, so it gets all of the MD5s into a list.

Some types of hashes can be missing for each entry.
NB: I just need to fix this, not completely rewrite it from scratch.

###code

```
example = {
    'iocs': {
        'high confidence': {
            'domains': ['evil.com',
                'bad.com'
            ],
            'ips': ['8.8.8.8'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6',
                'sha1': 'A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3',
                'sha256': '9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08'
            }]
        },
        'medium confidence': {
            'domains': ['test.com', 'lessbad.com'],
            'ips': ['10.10.10.10'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '5D41402ABC4B2A76B9719D911017C592',
                'sha1': 'AAF4C61DDCC5E8A2DABEDE0F3B482CD9AEA9434D',
                'sha256': '2CF24DBA5FB0A30E26E83B2AC5B9E29E1B161E5C1FA7425E73043362938B9824'
            }, {
                'sha256': '2CF24DBA5FB0A30E26E83B2AC5B9E29E1B161E5C1FA7425E73043362938B9824'
            }]

        },
        'low confidence': {
            'domains': ['nice.com', 'good.com'],
            'ips': ['2.2.2.2'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '7D793037A0760186574B0282F2F435E7',
                'sha1': '7C211433F02071597741E6FF5A8EA34789ABBF43',
                'sha256': '486EA46224D1BB4FB680F34F7C9AD96A8F24EC88BE73EA8E5A6C65260E9CB8A7'
            }]
        }
    }
}

for confidence, indicators in len(range(vendor_data.get('iocs'))):
md5s = ''
for hash_dict in vendor_data.get('hashes'):
    if hash_dict['md5']:
    md5s.append(hash_dict.get(md5))
```

Comment: Abhijit, there is nothing wrong with this question. OP, I'll get back to this tomorrow if someone else doesn't give you an answer by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes through the example data and gets all md5 hashes.

```py
example = {
    'iocs': {
        'high confidence': {
            'domains': ['evil.com',
                'bad.com'
            ],
            'ips': ['8.8.8.8'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F6',
                'sha1': 'A94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3',
                'sha256': '9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08'
            }]
        },
        'medium confidence': {
            'domains': ['test.com', 'lessbad.com'],
            'ips': ['10.10.10.10'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '5D41402ABC4B2A76B9719D911017C592',
                'sha1': 'AAF4C61DDCC5E8A2DABEDE0F3B482CD9AEA9434D',
                'sha256': '2CF24DBA5FB0A30E26E83B2AC5B9E29E1B161E5C1FA7425E73043362938B9824'
            }, {
                'sha256': '2CF24DBA5FB0A30E26E83B2AC5B9E29E1B161E5C1FA7425E73043362938B9824'
            }]

        },
        'low confidence': {
            'domains': ['nice.com', 'good.com'],
            'ips': ['2.2.2.2'],
            'hashes': [{
                'md5': '7D793037A0760186574B0282F2F435E7',
                'sha1': '7C211433F02071597741E6FF5A8EA34789ABBF43',
                'sha256': '486EA46224D1BB4FB680F34F7C9AD96A8F24EC88BE73EA8E5A6C65260E9CB8A7'
            }]
        }
    }
}

for confidence, indicators in example['iocs'].items():
    for indicator_type, indicator_list in indicators.items():
        for indicator in indicator_list:
            if indicator_type == 'hashes':
                for hash_type, hash_value in indicator.items():
                    if hash_type == 'md5':
                        print(hash_value)
```